# Is creating a new statement from a connection commit everything even if auto commit is false?

Tags: sql, jdbc, transactions, commit, h2db

I have the following code:

```
import java.sql.*;

class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloJdbc hj = new HelloJdbc();
        hj.insertPerson();
        hj.printPersons();
        hj.close();
    }
}

class HelloJdbc {

    String url = "jdbc:h2:~/persons";
    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";

    // Active connection
    Connection con;

    public HelloJdbc() {
        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password); Statement st = con.createStatement();
            // Making sure I have the same data every time
            st.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM person");
            st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO person VALUES (1, 'Alice');");
            this.con = con;
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }

    void insertPerson() {
        try {
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            con.createStatement().executeUpdate("INSERT INTO person VALUES(2, 'Bob');");
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }

    void printPersons() {
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);) {
            ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person;");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getObject(1) + " " + rs.getObject(2));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {}
    }

    void close() {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

When I run this code, the output will be:

```
1 Alice
```

This I understand, since in `insertPerson` I have `con.setAutoCommit(false);`

However, when I change the `printPerson` method as follows, so that instead of a new connection, it uses the active connection:

```
void printPersons() {
    try {
        ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person;");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getObject(1) + " " + rs.getObject(2));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {}
}
```

The output changes to:

```
1 Alice
2 Bob
```

I am confused, does creating a new statement from a connection commits everything from a prior statement? What is the cause of the behavior change?

Compile & run with `javac App.java; java -cp ".:h2.jar" App;` where you have `h2.jar` in the same folder with `App.java`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a connection performs an insert,  update, or delete inside a transaction then other statements of that *same connection* will be able to see the changes even if those changes have not been committed so that *other connections* can see them.

(Actually, under normal circumstances other connections cannot see the changes until they are committed, but a transaction with the isolation level of READ_UNCOMMITTED will allow other connections to see the changes before the original connection performs a commit or a rollback.)